# prevent angularjs from rebinding when navigating to another view

Tags: angularjs

I added a console.log to a method in my controller that is being bound from my view. I can see that it is binding as expected when this particular view loads. The problem is, when I click a link in this particular view to navigate to another view, the method is being called again. Is there a way to turn this off? I don't want it to rebind when navigating away.

```
.controller('FeedCtrl', function ($scope, FeedFactory, $location, $stateParams) {

$scope.bindChart = function (m1, m2, m3, index) {

        console.log('binding chart');
        new ChartService().buildTriangleChart(m1, m2, m3, index);

}

})
```

The above console.log gets called when loading the page(as expected) and also gets called when navigating to another page(not expected). Basically I don't want any binding to be called on the page that is being navigated away from.

The html code that is binding to the method 'bindChart()' is shown below:

```
<div ng-bind="bindChart(dateFeed.glucoseBefore.glucoseReading, dateFeed.glucose1HrAfter.glucoseReading, dateFeed.glucose2HrsAfter.glucoseReading, $parent.$parent.$parent.$index.toString() + $index.toString())"></div>
```

Comment: some code is always appreciated to make things a bit clearer

Comment: you many call the function on ng-init or u many use the same controller in other view also . if u put your code can give solution

Comment: One thing worth mentioning. I am using the Ionic framework for mobile development.